# Instantiating collections

Tags: c#, object, instantiation

I'm trying to understand how the line:

```
private Queue<IProductable> inventory { get; set; }
```

It is used in the entire code below.  I'm only used to seeing properties defined using simple types; so, this really confused me.   Also, I'm curious why the constructor for the class Factory (below) uses:

```
inventory = new Queue<IProductable>();
```

Instead of:

```
Queue<IProductable> inventory = new Queue<IProductable>();
```

My understanding is when you instantiate an new object, you should do:  `CLASS/TYPE newObjectName = new CLASS/TYPE`.  Is the constructor even instantiating a new "inventory" object?  If so, why don't I have to specify what type the object "inventory" is (in order to use it to invoke methods from the generic Collections class, Queue).

Anyway, below, is the code.  I'm hoping someone can explain this in the easiest possible way for me to comprehend/remember when I need to do something similar in the future.

```
namespace codeExample
{
    class Factory
    {
        private Queue<IProductable> inventory { get; set; }

        public Factory()
        {
            inventory = new Queue<IProductable>();
        }

        public IProductable GetOldestItem()
        {
            IProductable oldestItem = inventory.First();
            return oldestItem;
        }

        public IProductable GetNewestItem()
        {
            IProductable newestItem = inventory.Last();
            return newestItem;
        }

        public void Add(IProductable productToAdd)
        {
            inventory.Enqueue(productToAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `private Queue<IProductable> inventory { get; set; }` declares an [auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), but it could as well have been a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx):

```
private Queue<IProductable> inventory;
```

This declares a `private` [instance variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691163%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which you can access from any method in this class, but not from derived classes or from outside the class.

Your code assigns a value in the constructor, which is always run before other code in the class:

```
inventory = new Queue<IProductable>();
```

So now from everywhere in this class you can access `inventory`.

Comment: I think I understand everything up until declaring a private instance variable.  However, I'm still having trouble comprehending where in the code "inventory = new Queue<IProductable>();" is needed.

Comment: An assignment to `inventory`, like `inventory = new Queue<IProductable>()`, is at least needed before you access `inventory` for the first time anywhere else. Currently it is initialized in your constructor, which in this case seems to be a good choice. It being an instance variable means every instance of its containing class gets to access its own `inventory` variable.

Comment: I think what's confusing me is "Factory.inventory" is a property; which can hold a value; however, I can't figure out how references such as "inventory.First()" are related to that property.

Comment: @MKANET using `inventory.First()` inside that class's methods is the same as using `this.inventory.First()`. It points to the `inventory` field (or property) of the current instance (see [`this` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is when you instantiate an new object, you should do: CLASS/TYPE newObjectName = new CLASS/TYPE. Is the constructor even instantiating a new "inventory" object?

If the type were included then it would be creating a new local variable.  Currently the code is not creating a new variable, it is using the property instead, which is a part of that class's instance data (at least in this case).  The property (in this specific context) acts almost exactly like a private field would.  It is creating a variable that exists for the lifetime of the whole object, not just one method.

> Is the constructor even instantiating a new "inventory" object?

It's creating a new queue object, yes.  The property definition defines where a queue may be stored, but it doesn't create an actual queue.  The constructor actually creates a queue (which is empty) and assigns is to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private Queue<IProductable> inventory { get; set; }
```

is an [auto property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

it's equivalent to

```
 private Queue<IProductable> _inventory;
 public Queue<IProductable> Inventory 
 {
     get { return _inventory; }
     set { _inventory = value; }
 }
```

Thus, you just declared a member inventory, and later on you instantiate a `Queue<IProductable>` and store its reference to the auto property `inventory`.

```
inventory = new Queue<IProductable>();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm only used to seeing properties defined with simple types; so, this
>   really confused me

Why? You can define properties of any type.

> Also, I'm curious why the constructor for the class Factory (below)
>   uses:

You can't define the type of the property again, it's already available in the current scope because it's a class property. Its type is defined at the line `private Queue<IProductable> inventory { get; set; }`

> My understanding is when you instantiate an new object, you should do:
>   CLASS/TYPE newObjectName = new CLASS/TYPE

No, here is a simple counter-example in two lines:

```
MyType myVariable;
...
myVariable = new MyType();
```

Answer (score 0):

`private Queue<IProductable> inventory { get; set; }` is an automatic property.  The implementation of get/set are provided by the compiler.

vs

`Queue<IProductable> inventory = new Queue<IProductable>();`

Now, `inventory` is a field.  Properties have backing stores and are smarter than fields.  They allow a programmer to do work during get/set operations.

> Is the constructor even instantiating a new "inventory" object?

Yes, in the example the constructor is setting the hidden variable (backing store).

> If so, why don't I have to specify what type the object "inventory" is
>   (in order to use it to invoke methods from the generic Collections
>   class, Queue).

Because you are not declaring a new variable in the constructor.  We are *setting* a property.

*Here you could use a field instead of a property.  However, I would expect an "advanced class"/Factory to use Dependency Injection and thus a public property would make sense in such a case.  (Maybe you simplified the original code?)*